# Is there a shortcut to denote the absolute full directory of current path?

Tags: path, ln

Let's say that I am currently in `/a/b/c/d/e/`, and I want to make symbolic link with a file `f.txt` in that directory. If I do `ln -s f.txt /etc/`, the file `/etc/f.txt` will not point to the file, because it just points `f.txt`, not `/a/b/c/d/e/f.txt`. I have tried `ln -s ./f.txt /etc/`, but that created a link literally to `./f.txt`.

So, other than typing the full path myself, like `/a/b/c/d/e/f.txt`, is there any shortcut to tell `ln` that I want to use the absolute path of the file in the current directory?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to use command like:

```
ln -s "$(pwd)/f.txt" /etc/
```

The command `pwd` will add the current path to the filename.

Answer (score 0):

`ln` command has the option `--relative` however I'm not sure if this a GNUism since I did not found anything related to `--relative` in POSIX manual (`man 1p ln`).

From `man ln` (option 1) or `ln --help`:

> -r, --relative
>
> > with -s, create links relative to link location

So if you have Linux (with gnu software) you can use:

```bash
ln -s --relative f.txt /etc/
```

Answer (score -2):

Another solution:

```
ln -s ${PWD}/f.txt /etc/
```

Comment: @Kusalananda I like curly braces around variables.

Comment: Whatever you like, you should be quoting it